# I need to print the two-dimensional list mult_table by row and column

Tags: python

I have this so far but I get told I am not to have an ' | ' at the end, just in between.

```py
user_input= input()
lines = user_input.split(',')

# This line uses a construct called a list comprehension, introduced elsewhere,
# to convert the input string into a two-dimensional list.
# Ex: 1 2, 2 4 is converted to [ [1, 2], [2, 4] ]

mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end=' | ')
    print()
```

these are the errors I am getting.

```
Testing with input: '1 2 3,2 4 6,3 6 9'
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Your output
1 | 2 | 3 | 
2 | 4 | 6 | 
3 | 6 | 9 | 
Expected output
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
Testing with input: '1 2 3 4,2 4 6 8,3 6 9 12,4 8 12 16'
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Your output
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 
3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 
4 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 
Expected output
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
2 | 4 | 6 | 8
3 | 6 | 9 | 12
4 | 8 | 12 | 16
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't post images of data or examples, post text please. It was better before. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: sorry still new here, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current method, you’ll have to check if the element is the last element in a numerical loop and change the end accordingly:

```py
for row in mult_table:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        cell = row[i]
        print(cell, end=' | ' if i!=len(row)-1 else '')
    print()
```

An alternative method is to use the sep.join(list) method, where the string `sep` is added between all the elements and put in a string:

```py
for row in mult_table:
    print(' | '.join([str(cell) for cell in row]))
```

**Edit:** Convert cells to strings.

Comment: I tried for row in mult_tables: print(' | '.join(row)) and it says they are int and couldnt do that

Comment: Your first one solved my problem but could you explain it so I understand it better please?

Comment: In the first solution, first we switch the cells loop to a numerical loop so we can have some information to determine if we’ve hit the last cell in the row. While we’re printing the cell, we add the end argument conditionally, if it’s the last cell, add no character, if not, add the separating character for the next cell to come.

Comment: thank you this has helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

This type of output is expected because you are using :

> print(cell, end=' | ')

This results is adding ' | ' after each cell is printed.

Instead you can print the whole row adding ' | ' between the row elements using join(). But this requires the elements of row to be string. Therefore, the following code can be used :

```
row = [str(cell) for cell in row]
for row in mult_table:
    print(" | ".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing each cell with a `|` at the end in:

```
print(cell, end=' | ')
```

You can either check if this is the last cell and only print that pipe symbol if there's more to come, or just print them all in one go, joined together with `' | '`, like this:

```py
for row in mult_table:
    print(' | '.join(row))
    print()
```